# Insert inline code snippet has weird formatting when putting giant SVG path in HTML box

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I was working on an answer and notice when I copy pasted the SVG code for an answer, the formatting completely barfed. I imagine it has to do with the fact that the SVG path code is just really really long. See the picture:

[image]

And it it helps, this is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46310108/1168661) (just go to edit and edit my question in the code snippet editor). It happens on Chrome version 61.0.3163.79.

Comment: @Kaiido hmm potentially related although that seems to have issues more with number of lines rather than length of the lines.

Answer (score 5):

The bug lies in [*all.css*](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1e201fd2ade3) where a rule sets the `max-height` of `<pre>` elements to be `600px` <sub>(around char 93925 in current minified file).</sub>

Since there is also an `overflow: visible` rule set on `.CodeMirror pre`, when a line of code gets converted in `<pre>` and has its height > 600px, you'll see its content overflow over the following contents.

A simple fix would be to add in the `.CodeMirror pre` cssRule a `max-height:none;` overriding property.

Comment: As a feature, it would be nice to have this option available during snippet stack editing, or at least mentioned somewhere else other than Meta.