# Add toggle line wrap in snippet editor

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I pasted a really long line of code into the snippet editor—so long that the editor decided to ignore the rest of it. Here you can see that it has overflowed to the next line (for some reason, there's a maximum height?).

[image]

And I was a little disappointed that there wasn't any checkbox to wrap the lines. Maybe we could put it here?

[image]

*Artist's rendition*

Comment: Having the option where you've shown it would imply that the line wrapping would occur in the actual post, not just in the snippet editor. Giving *that* ability to authors isn't desirable, IMO. However, I don't think that's what you're asking for. I think you are only requesting wrapping for the author, personally, and only in the snippet editor. If so, the control for it would need to be somewhere else.

Comment: @Makyen Ah then it could probably be where "Tidy" and "Reset" are, then? Those two buttons are for the author and so if there was a "Wrap lines" button next to them I think it'd be more clear.

Comment: Was it a long line without any spaces (after some leading ones)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Only 1 space (variable declaration); you can actually see it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74294810/18244921) when you try to edit the snippet. I minified the given input so it wouldn't get in the way of the solution.

Comment: The original issue is basically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356783 Fixing that would already be great I guess.